# How to use environment variable in Typescript properly?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to make a simple api using typescript and when I use any env variable I get an error from TS compiler Tells me that this could be `undefined`

example

// Not Working

```
const db = process.env.DB_URL   // This gives an error that the result could be a string or undefined
```

to fix this
I have to make a type guard and check with if statement as follows

```
const db = process.env.DB_URL   

if (db){
  // ....
}
```

**Is there a better approach to to such a thing instead of explicitly check for every variable ?**

Comment: Yes, using a conditional check provides both type safety and runtime safety.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply null check and keep it as string instead of defining two types:

```
const db: string = process.env.DB_URL ?? ''

// empty strings are falsy/falsey
if (db) { // do this}
else { //do this}
```

Comment: this what I'm doing for now ,and my question is there a better approach ?

Comment: This is a better approach, you are doing both here type safety and runtime safety.